# Find Movies where an actor with first and last name has worked using Java 8 Streams, map, filter, reduce

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream, reduce

I am trying to playaround with Java 8 Stream API and wanted to convert the following method using Java 8 stream filter map reduce.

I have a list of Movies and every Movie object has a list of Actors along with other fields.

I want to find all the movies where the actor with a specific first and last name has worked in it.

The method below is Java 7 based where I loop over the list of Movies and then loop over a list of actors for that movie. If an actor with that first and last name is found, I break the inner loop and add that movie to the list of movies which is returned.

The commented code works and I can get the right list of Movies.

My question is how can I re-write this code using Java 8 streams. I can see it is a map, filter, reduce problem but I am not able to come up with a clear solution.

```
public List<Movie> getMoviesForActor(String firstName, String lastName) {

    final List<Movie> allMovies = movieRepository.getAllMovies();
    final Predicate<Actor> firstNamePredicate = actor -> actor.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName);
    final Predicate<Actor> lastNamePredicate = actor -> actor.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastName);

    final List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
    //        for (Movie movie : allMovies) {
    //            boolean actorFound = false;
    //            for (Actor actor : movie.getActors()) {
    //                if(firstName.equalsIgnoreCase(actor.getFirstName()) && lastName.equalsIgnoreCase(actor.getLastName())) {
    //                    actorFound = true;
    //                    break;
    //                }
    //            }
    //            if(actorFound) {
    //                movies.add(movie);
    //            }
    //        }

    final List<Actor> actors = allMovies.stream()
            .flatMap(
                    movie -> movie.getActors().stream().filter(firstNamePredicate.and(lastNamePredicate))
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return movies;
}
```

If I stream on the movies and flatmap it and in it stream list of actors, how can I get the list of movies again where only this actor with first and last name exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the first matching element while looping over an iterable and breaking once it is found can easily be achieved using the `anyMatch` short-circuiting terminal operation in Java8. Then pass the result of `anyMatch` to the `filter` operator to get all the movies matching the given criteria.

I would rather suggest you using inline predicates instead of defining them separately unless you reuse them somewhere else. This leads to more condensed code which is less verbose. Here's how it looks.

```
movies.stream()
    .filter(m -> m.getActors().stream()
        .anyMatch(
            a -> a.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName) 
                && a.getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastName)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For some reason if you really need to use the pre-defined predicates as given in your problem statement you can do it like so,

```
movies.stream()
    .filter(m -> m.getActors().stream()
        .anyMatch(firstNamePredicate.and(lastNamePredicate)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the other answers already addressed the ways you can solve the problem in `java-8`, with this solution you can use the all new [`Collectors.filtering`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#filtering-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.stream.Collector-) introduced in `java-9`.So just leaving it here for future reference.

```
List<Movie> movies = allMovies.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.filtering(
                      m -> m.getActors().stream().anyMatch(firstNamePredicate.and(lastNamePredicate)),
                Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Interesting alternative. Just to remember, *The `filtering()` collectors are most useful when used in a multi-level reduction, such as downstream of a `groupingBy` or `partitioningBy`*.

Answer (score 2):

Just a better way(functional) of writing it with your existing code would be:

```
final Predicate<Movie> movieIncludesActor = movie -> movie.getActors()
        .stream()
        .anyMatch(firstNamePredicate.and(lastNamePredicate)); // check both the condition for all actors
final List<Movie> movies = allMovies.stream()
        .filter(movieIncludesActor) // movie which has such an actor
        .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

And just one more solution.

Sometimes using the wrong collection type makes life difficult for you. I would suggest `Movie.getActors()` returns a `Set<Actor>` instead of a `List<Actor>`. This would make processing much easier.

```
private class Movie {
    public Set<Actor> getActors() {
        return null;
    }
}

private class Actor {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;

    private Actor(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Actor)) return false;
        Actor actor = (Actor) o;
        return firstName.equals(actor.firstName) &&
                lastName.equals(actor.lastName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(firstName, lastName);
    }
}

final List<Movie> allMovies = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;

public List<Movie> getMoviesForActor(String firstName, String lastName) {
    Actor actor = new Actor(firstName, lastName);

    return allMovies.stream()
            .filter(m -> m.getActors().contains(actor))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```